# What Would be a Sinusoidal Function that can Only Have Roots at all the Points I Have Highlighted?

Tags: periodic-functions

I am interested in a function which can represent the roots of the two functions which they do not share in common.
The red function is y=sin((pi/2)x) and the green one is y=sin((pi/3)x)
If anyone could provide help that would be awesome. The sketch is the blue function, the shape isn't necessary, only the fact that is has the roots indicated. 
[Sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHKCh.jpg)
[Sin(pi/2 x) and Sin(pi/3 x)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHIsy.png)

Comment: Why don't you sketch a function and show us?

Comment: Well, I could just draw a sinusoidal function passing through those points, but its shape would be arbitrary to its purpose. It only needs to pass through those points and nothing else.

Comment: OK, I understand your point. Sketch it and then then we can apply Fourier.

Comment: Okay, sketched.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a weird solution:

$$y = \frac{\sin(\frac\pi2 x)\sin(\frac\pi3 x)}{\sin^2(\frac\pi2 x) + \sin^2(\frac\pi3 x)}$$

[image]

We feed in $\sin(\frac\pi2 x)$ and $\sin(\frac\pi3 x)$ into the classic analysis counterexample $f(x,y) = \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$.

Comment: Thats wonderful, maybe I can elude to what I am doing. Say you kept plotting the next f(x) with half periods consecutively increasing by 1 and you wanted to continue passing a function through the points which the set of functions don't share. I would conjecture that if you had a method for this and took the limit as n (the half period) goes to infinity, you would pass a function through all the prime numbers.

Comment: Just curious, am I right?

Comment: That's a more complicated question. How do you know that the sequence of the functions converges to a limit?

Comment: Thats something to find out, but do you see my idea?

Comment: Sure, if you could construct a function whose zeros are the numbers that appear exactly once in the sequences $(2,4,6,...), (3,6,9,...), (4,8,12,...), ...$ then its zeros would be the prime numbers. But one could probably construct such a function directly without going through this limiting process.

Comment: In this instance, a zero would not fall in the sequence 4n, and if it is possible, why hasn't it been done

Comment: @Jack I'm sure it has been done, it just isn't useful enough to be well-known.  There are plenty of ways to construct real-valued functions that have zeroes exactly at the prime numbers.

Answer (score 0):

We can define a stepwise function as :

From x = 2 + 12$k$  to 4 + 12$k$ and $k\in\mathbb{Z}$:
$$y = sin(2\pi(x-2)/2)$$
From x = 4 + 12$k$   to 8 + 12$k$ :
$$y = sin(2\pi(x-4)/8)$$
From x = 8 + 12$k$   to 10 + 12$k$   :
$$y = - sin(2\pi(x-8)/2)$$
From x = 10 + 12$k$   to 14 + 12$k$   :
$$y = - sin(2\pi(x-10)/8)$$

For sure this is not the only one. We can adjust the slope to be equal at x = 2,4,8,10,... Also we can adjust amplitude.

Hope this simple one be of help.

**EDIT**

Here there is another one:

$$y = sin(2\pi(x-3)/12)+ 0,5  sin(2\pi(x-1)/4)$$

Comment: Can one function be passed through instead of a combination of 4? I would really like to elude to what I am trying to accomplish except I can't because I think someone would take it.

Answer (score 0):

If the shape isn't necessary, then how about:

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
0 &\textrm{ if $x$ is a root of exactly one of the two functions}\\
1 &\textrm{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$